"Since 14 years old, you know, 'right down the street' at Wimbledon." | Does it refer to the actual street or the closeness of the place?
On TV, a tennis player is talking about her book. The presenter asked her "What made you wanna write this book?" And she answers. At one point she said:

Yeah, I have learnt so much obviously from playing sport. Since 14 years old, you know, right down the street at Wimbledon. It was good times. ITV- Tennis legend's book (see:0:38-0:44)

By "right, down the street", I thought she meant, at 14, she played outside in the streets in Wimbledon like other children, so she learnt tennis playing in the street, but then I thought she can't have played tennis in the street because tennis is not something that you can play in the street.
Then I thought maybe she meant that the tennis court where she attended for training was close to her house, which is why she must have said "right down the street at Wimbledon". But I can't be sure.
So, by saying "right down the street", does she mean "the tennis court was close to her house." or does she mean "She used to played tennis actually in the street"?

Notice that she says at Wimbledon.  And you have mispunctuated, "right, down".  right modifies "down", so no comma. right there is not a response tag to the interviewer, indicating that the interviewer had said something apt or true.

Note that in American English, right / just down the street is as common as just down the road, but in British English we're much more likely to say just down the road when we mean not very far away, within walking distance.

Venus Williams is American; she didn't grow up near to Wimbledon. ITV's 'This Morning' is filmed in London, so she must mean 'down the street' from the TV studio.
The All England Tennis Club isn't literally 'down the street' from ITV's Television Centre; it's just a way of saying 'near here'. Venus became a professional tennis player at 14 and played at Wimbledon for many years.

+1.  If she were saying that she had played tennis since age 14 at some courts quite near Wimbledon, it would have been "right down the street from Wimbledon".

+1. She means “right near where we are now conversing.”

right down the street means very close to where I am (or was), or very close to where we are (or were), and it means on this same street when it's "we" and "the street where I lived" when it is "I" and the reference is to childhood.

When I was a kid, there was a candy store right down the street (from my house). ["from my house" is unnecessary but optional]


Could you please tell me where the florist shop is? My GPS says I'm at my destination but I don't see it.
-- It's right down the street on the left. They moved recently.

That is likely to mean "on this same block", as "right" in this context means "quite near". If it were somewhat farther away, it would be:

It's down the street a ways.
It's down the street a bit.

or something like that.
If it is quite far away on this same street it would be

It's down the street a good ways.


very good examples, thanks. I appreciate that.

"Down the street" means in the same street as, say, Wimbledon. Adding "right" suggests that it is also quite close.
I can't find a definition of "right down the street", but the Cambridge Dictionary defines "right around the corner" as

very close to the place that you are

For what it's worth, don't expect high standards of grammar from sportspersons- either participants or commentators.

So, she meant the tennis court she attended at 14 was in the same street as her house was, didn't she?

@Yunus - She didn't mean that, and, as far as I can tell, she never had a home in London.
